# Prevent sudo user access to specific folder and files

Tags: sudo, directory

How can I restrict `sudo` access to a specific user in the `/var` directory or its contents?

Comment: `sudo` is used to restrict access to commands, rather than specific directories.  Can you describe in a bit more detail what you're trying to achieve?  What commands do you want this user to be able to execute or what actions are they trying to carry out?

Comment: i have an objection that sudo user must not be able to view and edit logs. so that i need to restrict sudo user to change directory to some specific directories.

Comment: read [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/200911/how-to-prevent-access-to-a-folder-by-other-users) and [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79147/protect-folder-from-sudoers).

Comment: What *do* you want the user to be able to do as root?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` allows regular users to run commands as root.  Unless you provide an explicit list of very specific commands it is virtually impossible to prevent a user with `sudo` access from doing anything they like (and subsequently covering their tracks) with content that doesn't leave the server.

Your question is usually triggered by people who don't really grasp what `sudo` is doing.

So, the only way to achieve what you want using `sudo` is to limit the configuration to specific commands that don't accept any parameters.

`sudo` gives users root access (to everything, or to a subset of commands or to everything with some commands excluded).

If you don't trust users not to modify logs, then don't give them `sudo` access, because `sudo` access is just root access unless you're exceptionally careful and provide only specific commands (usually scripts) which achieve single specific goals.

Comment: okay... what about if we restrict user on command level. like we say a user can not use vi and rm commands

Comment: Then you're in an arms race with people you gave root access to but don't trust. If you allow sudo access to `cp` then people can use it to copy `vim` to a binary called `bob` and launch it.  The only safe way is to explicitly **include** commands, not exclude unsafe ones, but even then you have to be careful (can't give them `chmod` for example, because it can be exploited to give them access to anything).